# Failed to write data to connection Adress (neo4j python

Tags: python, neo4j

I use the neo4j python driver to write to my database.

I have my neo4j DB setup and was using ita few days ago without any issues. 
Today i run my code and i get the following error:

```
Failed to write data to connection Address(host='localhost', 
port=7687) (Address(host='xxx.x.x.x', port=7687)); 
("0; 'Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:xxxx)'")
```

When i check via the browser and execute MATCH (n) RETURN n, it appears that all my querys still get executed bc i can find nodes in the database.

I shut my pc down, reinstalled neo4j and basically everything else. 
(Its not only for CREATE statements but also for match statemenets)

Answer (score 4):

Adding this at the end of the script worked for me.

```
db.driver.close()
```

Comment: no it did not for me :) only the mentioned downgrading of packages worked. Im not informed if the current version has fixed it, since i froze my environment

Answer (score 3):

I also had faced this issue while connecting to neo4j using neo4j python driver.
Which has resolved by closing the driver after the execution.I have added below command on the end of the script worked for me.

```
driver.close()
```

Comment: This solved it for me as well, is there a particular reason why this solves the issue? Happy to get unstuck but uneasy about not understanding *why* this occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but maybe future developers can do something with it.

I had the same problem in **Neo4j 5.2.0** with **Neo4j Bolt Driver for Python (neo4j) v5.5.0** for **Python 3.10**.

I accidentaly created a new Driver object for each transaction which produced alot of stale connections. These stale connections send a "Goodbye" message before closing and re-opening a connection, as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/706).

Caching the driver and executing `driver.close()` in the right place did the trick.

According to the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/), transactions should be executed using the [`with`-statement](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/), to ensure that Driver and Session objects are properly closed after usage.

Comment: THANKS!!! ,I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Asusming you're using this driver, I suspect it might be related to [this bug](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/293) in `neo4j-python-driver`. It looks like their latest version fixes the bug, according to comments in the thread, but if not, maybe just downgrade back to whatever you were running before, and you should be fine.

It's usually a good idea to lock down your dependencies to avoid problems like this. Have a look at tools like `pipenv` or `poetry` if you're not familiar with them, they should save you a few headaches.

Comment: might be it. 

I tried using different neo4j versions, 3.5.6 and 3.5.9 and also different neo4j-python-driver versions even though there seem to be no older versions then 1.7 

Can't get rid of the error.

Im confused since i did not actively upgrade or downgrade before

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain where the issue lies, but the solve it to downgrade to python driver versions:

neo4j: 1.72

neobolt: 1.75

neotime: 1.75